# How to filter out cross alignments from a BED file?

Tags: sam, bed, genomics

I have a BAM file:

```
@SQ SN:chr1 LN:248956422
@SQ SN:chrx LN:248956423
ST-E00110:348:HGVKKALXX:1:1201:5822:48670   323 chr1    9999    0   67H66M16H   chrx    1000    0   GATAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAAC  JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJAJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJFJFJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJA77FJFJJJ  NM:i:0  MD:Z:66 AS:i:66 XS:i:65 SA:Z:chr5,18606834,-,73S76M,34,0;   RG:Z:g1
```

There is a read aligned to `chr1`, and it's mate aligned to `chrx`.

I have a BED file:

```
chr1    0   100000  TestOnly
```

I would like to filter out everything that falls outside my BED region, that includes cross-alignments. In my example, although my read aligned to `chr1` but it's mate is not. I don't want this read.

When I do:

> samtools view -L test.bed test.bam

the command gives me the read because it doesn't check cross-alignments.

My solution:

> samtools view -L test.bed test.bam | grep -v chrx

but this is very slow and clumsy. In my production pipeline I would have to do something like:

> samtools view -L test.bed test.bam | grep -v chrx | grep -v ... | grep -v ... | grep -v ... | grep -v ...

**Q:** Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [SAM specification](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf), the 3rd field of a SAM line (`RNAME`) is:

> RNAME: Reference sequence NAME of the alignment. If @SQ header lines
>   are present, RNAME (if not ‘*’) must be present in one of the SQ-SN
>   tag. An unmapped segment without coordinate has a ‘*’ at this field.
>   However, an unmapped segment may also have an ordinary coordinate such
>   that it can be placed at a desired position after sorting. If RNAME is
>   ‘*’, no assumptions can be made about POS and CIGAR.

And the 7th field is (emphasis mine, missing "to" theirs):

> RNEXT: Reference sequence name of the primary alignment of the NEXT
>   read in the template. For the last read, the next read is the first
>   read in the template. If @SQ header lines are present, RNEXT (if not
>   ‘*’ or ‘=’) must be present in one of the SQ-SN tag. This field is set
>   as ‘*’ when the information is unavailable, **and set as ‘=’ if RNEXT is
>   identical RNAME**. If not ‘=’ and the next read in the template has one
>   primary mapping (see also bit 0x100 in FLAG), this field is identical
>   to RNAME at the primary line of the next read. If RNEXT is ‘*’, no
>   assumptions can be made on PNEXT and bit 0x20

So, you want to remove those lines whose 7th field isn't `=` and, just in case, those lines whose 7th field isn't `=` *and* isn't the same as the 3rd field. You can therefore use something like this:

```
samtools view -L test.bed test.bam | awk '$7=="=" || $3==$7
```

And, to save as a bam file again:

```
samtools view -L test.bed test.bam | awk '$7=="=" && $3==$7 | 
    samtolls view -b > fixed.bam
```

---

On a separate note, there's very rarely a need to chain multiple grep commands like that. You can just use `\|` (or `|` with the `-E` or `-P` options) to separate them. Something like:

```
samtools view -L test.bed test.bam | grep -v 'chrx\|chr2\|chr10\|chrN'
```

Or

```
samtools view -L test.bed test.bam | grep -Ev 'chrx|chr2|chr10|chrN'
```

Comment: If you do it like this, the `fixed.bam` file is missing the header, which in my experience generates a lot of problems. I recommend always adding the header back in; either by specifying `-h` when reading the original BAM, or by adding it separately: `(samtools view -H infile.bam; samtools view …) > samtools view -b > outfile.bam`.